# How to access children of CustomMultiChildLayout in the performLayout() method of the associated MultiChildLayoutDelegate?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a simple application where one can click on the surface to add a widget of some kind at that position. The ultimate goal would be to expand it into something like a mindmap maker tool later on. Therefore I was searching for a way to group multiple widgets and came across `CustomMultiChildLayout`. Since I am new to Flutter it may be already a strange start so if there is a better way of doing so please let me know.

This is what i came up with:

```
class _CardAppState extends State<CardApp> {
  List<Widget> cards = [];

  void _addCardAtPosition(Offset position) {
    setState(() {
      cards.add(CardWidget(cards.length, position)); // cards.length will be the id of that LayoutId
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerDown: (details) {
        _addCardAtPosition(details.localPosition);
      },
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: CustomMultiChildLayout(
          delegate: LayoutDelegate(),
          children: [
            ...cards,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is within the `LayoutDelegate` class I created.

```
class LayoutDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    for (var child in children) { // children does not actually exist!!!
      layoutChild(child, BoxConstraints.loose(size));
      positionChild(child.id, child.position);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

In order to display the cards inside the `List<Widget> cards` on the screen I have to call `layoutChild()` for each of them. But since I do not know the current length of `cards` I can't really loop through them. Maybe by simply passing down `cards` or using a while loop which loops until a certain `id` wasn't found by `hasChild()` but it would be a lot easier if I could just access something like `children`.

Further I assume that returning `false` in `shouldRelayout` additionally prevents my code from working but it also doesn't seem to be very smart to rebuild the layout all the time. I would be glad if someone could explain to me how this method actually works and how to use it in a more suitable way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: simply pass the IDs in `LayoutDelegate` construstir

Comment: "[...] but it also doesn't seem to be very smart to rebuild the layout all the time" - what do you mean by "rebuilding the layout all the time"?

Comment: @pskink I have to admit that I didn't quite understand what the method `shouldRelayout` does and when it gets called. However the documentation eventually helped me out. Btw thanks for your response. Passing the IDs into the `LayoutDelegate` completely did the trick.